# Difference between JSON.parse() & .json()

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

What is the difference between JSON.parse() and .json() method?

According to some articles on internet these two methods can work in similar manner and one can be used in place of the other one. But this is not the case when I am trying.
For example:

```
const URL = "...some url...";

const getResponse = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(URL);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  
  //following part is not working...
  const data1 = JSON.parse(res);
  consoloe.log(data1);
}
```

Comment: `.json` is a method on the response object ... `JSON.parse(res)` is trying to parse an object, but JSON.parse should be used on JSON, not objects - `JSON.parse(await res.text())` is more or less similar to `await res.json()`

Comment: JSON.parse takes argument as string. In You case fetch does not return string, it returns object with methods to work with. So You have to use await res.json() which already will parse string body and return usable data object, or You can use await res.text() which will return raw text body which You can JSON.parse.

Comment: "*According to some articles on internet these two methods can work in similar manner and one can be used in place of the other one*" evidently those articles are wrong as you found out. I suggest you stop using those sources if they claim something completely illogical like `.json()` and `JSON.parse()` being completely interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what these methods are doing.

```
const data = await res.json()
```

This will decode the buffer in `res` as a Javascript object. This means the resulting data is *not text*. If you for whatever reason want to have the result as a string, you need to call and await `res.text()`. If the data is not decodable, it will fail the promise.

`Response#json()` is async (returning a Promise), meaning you can let it do it's stuff in the background without blocking, whereas `JSON.parse()` is blocking.

---

**With regards to the failing code:**

```
const data1 = JSON.parse(res);
```

This does not make any sense. You are trying to parse a JS object. This would be equivalent to doing `JSON.parse({})`.

`JSON.parse` is meant to parse ( = make sense of) *text* (a string). This is typically its indended usecase:

```
const data = JSON.parse('{"a":1}');
typeof data.a // => `number`
```

---

You *could*, use `JSON.parse()` to decode results from the Fetch API. One usecase could be to be able to print the string that failed the decoding, doing something like this:

```
let text;
text = await res.text(); // it's ok if it throws, means it is not text
try {  
    return JSON.parse(text);
} catch (err) {
    throw new TypeError(`Caught exception trying to parse text as JSON. text='${text}'`);
}
```